# Is Visual F# backwards compatible?

Tags: f#

I am trying to find out if it is possible to replace parts of an older applications built in T-SQL with Visual F#?

Is Visual F# a stable language regarding updates? Ex, the meaning of reserved words change over time? Are some parts of the langue guaranteed to be backwards compatible? Will they remove some standardized functions in the future etc..?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

F# is pretty stable language (we use it in production since 2009 when it has version 2.0). Currently it has version 4.0 (previous versions specified here http://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/). I'm pretty sure that the meaning of reserved words etc. will not be changed.

P.S. In this answer I mean by `F#` the version of language known as `Visual F#` and distributed by Microsoft. Generally speaking F# is open sourced and there may be different `flavors` of language. See more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2015/10/23/a-letter-about-quot-f-quot-and-quot-visual-f-quot.aspx